# Surrounding query with parenthesis cause error For XML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When trying to wrap query for further processing I get an error by just putting parenthesis around the query.  See query below, if I simply remove the wrapping parenthesis, the query works.  But when I use the parenthesis I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'

```
(
select '; ' + [NAME]  
from (select a.[NAME] as 'NAME'
      from [MS].[dbo].[A_POSITIONS] a
      where a.ID = 208418           
      except 
      select top 1 b.[NAME] 
      from [MS].[dbo].[A_POSITIONS] b
      where b.ID = 208418) as c
for XML PATH(''),TYPE
)
```

Anyone have an idea on why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: is that your whole code?, nothing else?

Comment: yes it is the only code in the query window.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the parenthesis alone around your query leads to an error, but if you type a `SELECT` before the opening parenthesis the code will run, meaning that you can use it for further processing:

```
if OBJECT_ID('A_POSITIONS') is not  null
drop table [dbo].[A_POSITIONS]

create table [dbo].[A_POSITIONS]([ID] int,[Name] varchar(100))

insert into [dbo].[A_POSITIONS] values
(208418, 'one'),(208418, 'two'),(208418, 'three'),(208418, 'four'),(208418, 'five')

select
(
select '; ' + [NAME]  
from (select a.[NAME] as 'NAME'
    from [MS].[dbo].[A_POSITIONS] a
    where a.ID = 208418           
    except 
    select top 1 b.[NAME] 
    from [MS].[dbo].[A_POSITIONS] b
    where b.ID = 208418) as c
for XML PATH(''),TYPE
)
```

One last consideration: `TOP` keyword without an `ORDER BY` clause is non-deterministic.

From Microsoft Docs (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)):

> When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it returns the first N number of rows **in an undefined order**

So you should really consider adding an `ORDER BY` to the second part of your query:

```
select '; ' + [NAME]  
from (select a.[NAME] as 'NAME'
    from [MS].[dbo].[A_POSITIONS] a
    where a.ID = 208418           
    except 
    select top 1 b.[NAME] 
    from [MS].[dbo].[A_POSITIONS] b
    where b.ID = 208418
    --Add an ORDER BY clause here
) as c
for XML PATH(''),TYPE
```